# Simulink transitions and superstates, will you go back to the outside state?

Tags: matlab, simulink, state-machine, stateflow

I have a system setup like the sample stateflow:

[image: Sample Stateflow]

`Condition1` Occurs and we go to `Sub1`. If `Condition3` then occurs will it bring us back to `Test1`? Similarly if we get to `sub2` through `Condition1` and `Condition2` and then `Condition4` occurs will we go back to `Test1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this for yourself, define the `ConditionX` variables as local symbols to that Stateflow model, and some variable `x` which you can look at while stepping through the Stateflow evaluation. Set a breakpoint where the `Condition1` transition is (**right click the line, add breakpoint**) and then run your model to step through it.

In my screenshots I've shortened the `ConditionX` names to `cX`.

In short, no you won't re-enter `Test1` without a state transition back to it from `Super`. Control will be returned to the `Super` state (out of the `Sub1` state) and then follow the default transition back into `Sub1`.

So If `c1` and `c3` are true, `c2` is false.

1. Default transition into `Test1`, set `x=0`.
2. Transition from `Test1` to `Super` because `c1` is true.
3. Default transition into `Sub1`, set `x=1`.
4. Transition back to `Super` because `c2` is false (no transition to `Sub2`) but `c3` is true.
5. Repeat steps 3. and 4. `x=1` does not change again.

If `c2` is true then you transition into `Sub2` instead of step 4. above, `x=2`.

If `c4` is also true then you transition out of `Sub2` back into `Super`, and follow the default transition back into `Sub1`.

[image: example]

If you want to return to `Test1` then you need to add a default transition from `Super` to `Test1`. Note that in this trivial example `Condition1` is always true, so it would then immediately transition back into `Super` and `Sub1`.

[image: example with additional transition]